AWS API Gateway Lambda Authorizer with Path Parameters
I am using AWS API Gateway with a Lambda function as a request authorizer and have the following setup:
const requestAuthorizer = new RequestAuthorizer(this, "RequestAuthorizer", {
    handler: requestAuthorizerLambda,
    resultsCacheTtl: Duration.seconds(300),
    identitySources: [
        IdentitySource.header("authorization"),
        IdentitySource.context("path"),
    ],
});

Our API endpoint is:
POST /api/v2/automations/{automationId}/recipient
Problem
I check in the authorizer Lambda function if the automationId in the path parameter corresponds to an automation in a live state. If the automation is not in a live state, the request should be rejected. However, I am encountering an issue where:
When I reject a request for an automation that is not in a live state, subsequent or parallel valid requests for different automationId values are also rejected, even though they should be accepted. This happens even when I set resultsCacheTtl to 0 to disable caching.

How can I properly configure the API Gateway Lambda Authorizer to handle path parameters such as automationId? Any insights or solutions to correctly handle authorization for requests with different automationId values would be greatly appreciated.

$context.path is always /api/v2/automations/{automationId}/recipient in your case - it does not perform substitution for the actual values of the path parameter.
You are looking for the $context.routeKey parameter.
From the docs:

To cache responses per route, add $context.routeKey to your authorizer's identity sources.

